# appending User entered text using createTextNode method

Tags: javascript, html

Right now I am trying to figure out how to append CREATED text to a CREATED p element depending on what a user enters into an input text field.
If I set the text after the createTextElement method, it displays just fine when I click the button. BUT what I want is: the user enters text in the input field and then upon clicking the button, the text get's added to the end of the div tag with the id of "mydiv". Any help is appreciated.

HTML:

```
<body>
    <div id="mydiv">
        <p>Hi There</p>
        <p>How are you?</p>
        <p>
            <input type="text" id="myresponse">
            <br>
            <input type="button" id="showresponse" value="Show Response">
        </p>
        <hr>
    </div>
</body>
```

JAVASCRIPT:

```
var $ = function(id) {
    return document.getElementById(id)
}

var feelings = function()
{    
    $("myresponse").focus();

    var mypara = document.createElement("p");
    var myparent = $("mydiv");

    myparent.appendChild(mypara);

    var myText = document.createTextNode($("myresponse").value);

    mypara.setAttribute("id", "displayedresponse");

    mypara.appendChild(myText);

    $("displayedresponse").appendChild(myText);    
}

window.onload = function() {

    $("showresponse").onclick = feelings;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. You need to apply an argument to `createTextNode` function
2. You need to read the value of the input field so you can see the text.
3. Since you will reference *mydiv* on every click, i think moving mydiv variable to parent scope will suit you better

   ```
   var $ = function (id) {
     return document.getElementById(id)
   }
   let mydiv = $('mydiv');
   $("showresponse").addEventListener('click', feelings);

   function feelings() {
     let textInput = $('myresponse').value;
     var mypara = document.createElement("p");
     var myText = document.createTextNode(textInput);
     mypara.setAttribute("id", "displayedresponse");
     mypara.appendChild(myText);
     mydiv.appendChild(mypara);
    $("displayedresponse").appendChild(myText);
   }
   ```

Comment: super helpful, worked well. I up-voted your answer. Thank you!!

Comment: glad i could help :)